# Yii clickable td

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

I currently have a table with data retrieve from DB, and I wish the `td` are clickable to redirect to another page. So far I found a example bellow:

```
<td onClick="document.location.href='http://www.yoursite.com';"> some text here </td>
```

I still not sure this work or not, because im using Yii `Chtml::tag` to create table.

So my question is where to put the `onClick` function into `Yii td` ?

```
echo CHtml::tag('td', array('class'=>"td"),"-");
```

Or any other suggestion so I can click on the td to another page? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about trying this if your td has a class "td"

```
$('td.td').click(function(){
     //your redirect here
});
```